# Pivot a table in SQL with some columns retained from the original table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have some data in the following format:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | rank
--------------------------
  A  |  1   |  D1  | 1
  A  |  1   |  D2  | 2
  A  |  1   |  D3  | 3
  B  |  5   |  E!  | 1
  B  |  5   |  E@  | 2
  B  |  5   |  E#  | 3
  B  |  5   |  E$  | 4
  C  |  3   |  F1  | 1
  C  |  3   |  F2  | 2
```

I want to pivot it by col3, but want to retain the columns `col1, col2` in the resulting table. Also, when creating the pivot columns, I want to ensure that only up to a fixed rank is picked. For example, if the rank threshold is 3, the output would look like :

```
col1 | col2  | P1  | P2 |  P3
------------------------------
  A  |  1    | D1  | D2 | D3
  B  |  5    | E!  | E@ | E#
```

Explanation:

```
1. In the output, the two rows with ``col1==C`` are dropped since they don't meet the rank threshold 3. 
2. The row with ``col3==E$`` is dropped since it's rank is higher than the rank threshold 3.
```

Is there a way to achieve this with SQL Server?

Comment: Did you check the solution I have provided?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following with `case` statement and here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cbpgQZFTfGtuNqEnBgFJ6f/1).

```
with cte as
(
  select
    col1,
    col2,
    max(case when rank = 1 then col3 end) as P1,
    max(case when rank = 2 then col3 end) as P2,
    max(case when rank = 3 then col3 end) as P3
  from myTable
  group by
    col1,
    col2
)

select 
    *
from cte
where P1 is not null and P2 is not null and P3 is not null
```

Output:

```
| col1 | col2 | p1  | p2  | p3  |
| ---- | ---- | --- | --- | --- |
| A    | 1    | D1  | D2  | D3  |
| B    | 5    | E!  | E@  | E#  |
```